# Download text file from website directly to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1

Tags: download, text-files, azure-data-lake

Is it possible to download large text files from a website directly to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1; and if yes what are the steps I need to follow?  I don't have enough storage space on desktop and very slow to transfer data.

Comment: Hi RAH, If my answer is helpful for you, can you please mark it as answer?  This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hello RAH, haven't heard you for a long time and hope you are doing well. do you have any other questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, we can not download large text files from a website directly to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 directly.

You could using Data Factory to help you achieve that. Ref bellow tutorials:

1. [Copy data from an HTTP endpoint by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http): This article outlines how to use Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory to copy data from an HTTP endpoint. HTTP connector is generic to retrieve data from any HTTP endpoint, e.g. to download file.
2. [Load data into Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 by using Azure Data
   Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/load-azure-data-lake-store):This article shows you how to use the Data Factory Copy Data tool to load data from Amazon S3 into Data Lake Storage Gen1. You can follow similar steps to copy data from other types of data stores.
3. [Copy data to or from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 using Azure Data
   Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-store): This article outlines how to copy data to and from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1.

Using HTTP connector as Source and Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 as Sink.

Hope this helps.